# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, zxing, dex

I am trying to integrate barcodefraglibv2 into my android app in AndroidStudio. I tried to copy libs core.jar and barcodelib.jar into libs directory. However when I try to run application, I get following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':Blok:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /home/backman/android/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2/dx --dex --output /home/backman/AndroidStudioProjects/Blok/Blok/build/dex/debug /home/backman/AndroidStudioProjects/Blok/Blok/build/classes/debug /home/backman/AndroidStudioProjects/Blok/Blok/build/dependency-cache/debug /home/backman/AndroidStudioProjects/Blok/Blok/build/pre-dexed/debug/core-bcdbe5f84dd399255abb34d14ce9def109db2534.jar
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

I have no luck trying to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved,

I removed libraries, reload project, add libraries, removed my references to support-v4, removed libraries again, build, add libraries, build, added back references and build.

Comment: maybe faster: solved deleting all "build" subdirectories and re-building the whole project

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple copies of the classes in `zxing` in your app. You should likely have exactly one copy: the `core` .jar in `libs/` and nothing else.

Comment: Didn't find any. Just core.jar in libs folder

Comment: How about in your source tree, do you have a copy of the source too?

Comment: No, nothing in there either.

Comment: Look at the locations it is looking at. Maybe some stale artifacts in your build that you can clean or delete.

Comment: thanks man. Move to "project " perspective and you'll find the lib folder

Answer (score 2):

I removed from /libs folder and cleaned and rebuild it again.problem fixed

```
GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1
android-support-v4
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `Clean Project`
2. `Rebuild Project`
3. `Run`